# MAMP PRO /etc/hosts on MAC

Tags: macos, file, permissions, mamp, hosts

I have been using MAMP for a solid year right now so I decided to get the MAMP PRO version. When I registered MAMP PRO and tried to start the server it gave me an error like:

```
ERROR

The file /etc/hosts couldn't be written.

(null)
```

I tried doing several things like giving read & write permissions to the administrator account as well as my own, deleting the 127.0.0.1 line in the hosts file and many other things to get this fixed but nothing seems to be working. I am using the 3.4 version of MAMP PRO and I'm running OSX El Capitan.

I've also tried these solutions but they didn't work:
[/etc/hosts file permission Mamp Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850865/etc-hosts-file-permission-mamp-pro)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a common issue when switching to the pro version of MAMP. I recommend uninstalling both regular and pro versions. Then installing just the pro version.

This [link](https://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11088) shows the issue and it seems people have solved in different ways. But Uninstalling and reinstalling clean will solve it.

Comment: I've deleted MAMP literally like 10 times and it's still not working. I have deleted every file manually, I have uninstalled it using the uninstaller etc etc. I honestly have no idea what's going on because the MAMP free version is working fine...